# How can I add a PPA on Ubuntu using the python apt API?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, python, python-2.7

Using the Python apt API on python 2.7? I have not been able to find out how to do it.

Comment: Please [edit] and describe what you really want to achieve. There seems to be a mismatch of the title with the actual question. Adding a PPA is always done with `sudo apt-add-repository [ppa name]` but I guess you already know that and that isn't what you actually want to do.

Comment: This is a coding question and has not alot to do with Ubuntu. This is better suited over on SO and there you would find this as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537390/how-to-install-a-package-using-the-python-apt-api

Comment: Ubuntu's software center was built around that api so it has a lot to do with Ubuntu. The link that you posted though has nothing to do with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It is still a programming question. Programming issues are off topic here even if it's programming on, with and for Ubuntu.

Comment: This question is not offtopic for this site and shouldn't have been closed! Python is one of the most important languages in Ubuntu, and if you look at the About page for AskUbuntu, you'll see the first line says: «This is a free, community driven Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers.»  https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use Python 3, which shouldn't be a problem since current Ubuntu releases (aside from soon-to-be-EOL 12.04) all have Python 3 installed by default and are moving to using only Python3 by default. Use the [`aptsources.sourceslist.SourcesList`](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/aptsources.sourceslist.html#aptsources.sourceslist.SourcesList) object:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import aptsources.sourceslist as sl

sources = sl.SourcesList()
sources.add('deb', 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt', 'xenial', ['main'])
sources.save()
```

Comment: This works on python 2 too. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Odd. I got a "no module named ..." error. Probably didn't install the python2 bindings.

Comment: I know this is a year old but... I'm writing a Python  script using APT module and I'm getting an error at the sources.add(<args here)> method line.  I get this error --> TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'orig_comps'

Comment: @Alex did you include the components array? In the example it's the `['main']` argument. Use whatever component is appropriate for your case.

Comment: @muru so my problem is specifically when trying to pass architecture.  I'm in the process of  asking here but don't have all details yet.